# How to use {{ url '' }} in HTML with a variable for the url reference

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a project to develop a wiki. I have a page with the list of entries, and I would like each of the entries to be clickable and redirect to the appropriate page.

HTML

```
<ul>
    {% for entry in entries %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'entry' %}">{{ entry }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

The problem I'm facing is that I'm not sure how to put a variable inside my {% %} to get the href to point to the correct link. I'm not sure if it's helpful but here's the url parameterization as well:

```
urlpatterns = [
path("", views.index, name="index"), 
path("<str:entry>", views.markdown, name="entry"),
path("error", views.error, name="error")
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass it as a positional or named parameter, so with:

```
<li><a href="{% url 'entry' entry=entry %}">{{ entry }}</a></li>
```

Note that you should place the `error` path *before* the `entry` path, otherwise `error` will be seen as an entry with as `entry` parameter `'error'`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('error/', views.error, name='error'),  # before entry
    path('<str:entry>/', views.markdown, name='entry')
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do by placing the variable after the url like this,

```
<ul>
    {% for entry in entries %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'entry' entry %}">{{ entry }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```